# Bookshelf.js polymorphic relation query returns empty array

Tags: node.js, bookshelf.js

I defined my relations as required. A user has multiple photos and an a photo is belong to a user.

Why my query returns an empty photos[] array? (I'm attempting to get all photos of a given user)

Docs : http://bookshelfjs.org/#polymorphic

My image table structured like this:

images

```
id (auto increment and primary key)
imageable_type (user is given)
imageable_id (user_id is given)
```

models.js

```
var image = db.Model.extend({
    tableName: 'images',
    imageable: function () {
        return this.morphTo('imageable', user);
    }
});

var user = db.Model.extend({
    tableName: 'users',
    hasTimestamps: true,

    photos: function () {
        return this.morphMany(image, 'imageable');
    }
});

module.exports.user = user;
module.exports.image = image;
```

app.js

```
var user = require('./models').user;
var image = require('./models').image;

app.get('/photos', function (req, res) {
    user.where('id' , 1).fetchAll({withRelated: ['photos']}).then(function (data) {
        data = data.toJSON();
        res.send(data);
    });
});
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Problem solved.

It turns out you need to use the plural table name in images table, which is `users` in this case.

Comment: Care to explain more?